# type hierarchy with type parameters?

Tags: c#, inheritance

imagine this layout of classes i use for building a tree structure:

```
class Treenodebase
{
    Treenodebase Parent{get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Treenodebase> Children {get;set;}
}
class Specialtreenode : Treenodebase
{
    string SpecialProperty{get;set;}
    public string ParentsSpecialProperty()
    {
        return Parent.SpecialProperty; //here I'd need casting?!
    }
}
class Othertreenode : Treenodebase
{
    string OtherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I use the subclasses to build seperate trees throughout my program. that means each Specialtreenode only ever has a parent of type Specialtreenode, and also children of type Specialtreenode.

The snipped is very simplified. The base class has many more properties (like IsSelected and IsExpanded) and methods (think 'Ancestors' or 'Siblings' and the like) and the subclasses too.

Can I somehow utilize type parameters here to avoid casting within each of the subclasses? Or would that always involve my subclasses not inheriting from the baseclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
class Treenodebase<T> where T : Treenodebase<T>
{
    public T Parent{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<T> Children {get;set;}
}
class Specialtreenode : Treenodebase<Specialtreenode>
{
    string SpecialProperty{get;set;}
    public string ParentsSpecialProperty()
    {
        return Parent.SpecialProperty;
    }
}
```

Of course, this eliminates the non-generic `Treenodebase` type, which could be good or bad. If you have a lot of utility methods that don't really care what implementation you use, you might want to make `Treenodebase<T>` either extend a non-generic base class or implement a non-generic interface. On the other hand, you might find it easier to just make all your utility methods be generically typed as well. It depends on how you're using the tree in code.

Comment: i wasn't sure if this notion of recursive type parameters was possible but it seems like it. anyway, please see my update. does this eliminate the casting?

Comment: @Markus Hütter: Yes, it can. I had to change my example a little, though. See my updated code.

Comment: you are my hero! thanks, I was missing that bit with `where T : Treenodebase<T>`

Comment: @Markus Hütter: Yeah, the recursive type definition can be a little mind-boggling at first.